# How To Script A String of Google Drive File Parents?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am just a newb using Google App Scripts (nothing fancy). I want to get build a string for a file's location.

I am  trying the method [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents) however this is only returning the file's immediate parent, when I am expecting multiple parents -- since it's a collection (umm right... i think?).

**Updated**
To illustrate, see a potential folder structure in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb2cb.png). You can also view on [shared google drive here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MKOPx3U_A3fsaLxNajtQVrjIJsNzk7bh?usp=sharing).

For the file of `DEC_15_2020`, I would like to get each single folder parent all the way to my root directory. So in the illustration it would be:
`MyDrive\StackOverFlow\All_Time\2020\Q4\December\`

When I run my code, I am only getting the single parent (`December`).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how the best way to just get the string of test for a file's parents?

```
function getPath(theFile){
  var folders = theFile.getParents();
  var thePath = '';

  while(folders.hasNext()){
    var theFolder = folders.next();
    thePath= theFolder.getName() +'/' + thePath;
    }
    return thePath;
}
```

Comment: If it's only returning the immediate parent, why not keep calling`getParents` until you reach the root?

Comment: Hi @AbrarHossain, that's what I'm trying to do... but I must be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**USING DUMMY NAMES FOR EASING**

The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the parent folder of intake.doc.

   ```
   tpl is retrieved.
   ```
2. Retrieve the parent folder of tpl.

   ```
   MyDrive is retrieved.
   ```
3. Retrieve the folders under MyDrive.

   ```
   Client and tpl are retrieved.
   ```

```js
var tpl_intakeDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(docIDs.tpl_intake);
var parent = tpl_intakeDoc.getParents(); // tpl
if (parent.hasNext()) {
  var parentOnParent = parent.next().getParents(); // MyDrive
  if (parentOnParent.hasNext()) {
    var MyDrive = parentOnParent.next().getFolders();
    while (MyDrive.hasNext()) {
      var folder = MyDrive.next();
      Logger.log(folder.getName()) // tpl, Client
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is not producing the results I am expecting. I'll provide more detail in about an hour. To illustrate using my time example, this seems to return "October/November/December" when I am looking for "2020/Q4/December". I will share an example to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi again. If you look at my question, it included some screenshots and a shared folder structure where you can see sample. When I tried your approach I received `October\November\December`. I think I'm missing a critical component to how collections work. They seem practically the same as arrays. I haven't been able to find a clear difference assign from the methods such as `hasNext()`.